# How can I create a new image with transparent background in Paint.NET?

Tags: png, drawing, transparency, paint.net

I would like to do some basic graphics using Paint.NET. I would like to start with a transparent background and draw on top of it, but I can't find any settings on how to do that. I only get a new image with a white background.

How do I start drawing on a transparent background in Paint.NET?

I will save the image as a PNG file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could probably magic wand the white background, and delete it, or create a new layer, and hid the background before saving it.

Answer (score 6):

Currently I use to do CTRL+A (select all) and then `Delete` key, or `Edit`/`Erase selection`, on new images.

But I was searching for the same answer to have a new image with automatic transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

create an img which only has transparent background and when starting Paint.net open this file to work further

Comment: The question was **how** to do this. If I take `File > New...` there is no option to choose a transparent background.

Comment: you will need to use the eraser to get a transparent image (if you erased a patch of the img you may copy it as long as all the image is erasedd), then save it and load it everytime you start paint.net  .

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a new Layer - This is always transparent
2. Delete the Layer named "Background" - This is the white layer

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a new Layer - This is always transparent
2. Delete the Layer named "Background" - This is the white layer
3. Change the property of the new layer to visibility = true. This can be found on the Layers menu.